# Query to search an entire DB for a string

Tags: oracle, toad

I've been tasked to do a bit of data discovery work. I'm working with our in house application, and I need to determine the first few tables that get hit when we do specific actions in the application. I have no intimate knowledge with the DB other than the fact that there are 1000 different tables I need to account for.

During my search, I came across this link https://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2015/01/06/sql-to-search-for-a-value-in-all-columns-of-all-atbles-in-an-entire-schema/

Which is exactly what I need, but when I run it it's not returning any data. I've confirmed that it's not working as intended by going and grabbing some data that I KNOW is in the DB and searching for that.

Here's the query I'm running

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTR (:val, 1, 11) "Searchword",
  SUBSTR (table_name, 1, 14) "Table",
  SUBSTR (column_name, 1, 14) "Column"
FROM cols,
 TABLE (xmlsequence (dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype ('select '
 || column_name
 || ' from '
 || table_name
 || ' where upper('
 || column_name
 || ') like upper(''%'
 ||  :val
 || '%'')' ).extract ('ROWSET/ROW/*') ) )
 ORDER BY "Table"
 /
```

When I execute this query, TOAD pops up with a Variables screen in which I specify the type and value of :val. I hit OK, the query executes and returns nothing.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I just ran this query in TOAD and it worked fine. I am running it with F9, when the dialog pops up I specify varchar2, in, literal, and I enter the value without quotes. I tried it on multiple different values and all results were correct.

Comment: @BrianLeach I'm not sure. Unless my DB has restricted access of some sort that isn't allowing me to execute this query? Perhaps the xml .extract method requires some permissions or something?

Comment: It could indeed be a privilege issue. Are you logged in as the owner of the schema? Do you have select permission on all of the tables and views withing the schema?